# Search doesn't find certain words in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, ios-app

In the iOS app (version 1.2.2), when I go to Puzzling.SE and then type "Linux" into the "Search Questions" field near the top, it returns nothing:

[image]

But as you can see from the [web site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=Linux), there is a result for "Linux".

The iOS app also returned no results for "Java", even though the [web site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=Java) shows results for "Java".

Comment: Looks like the [search/excerpts API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=Linux&filter=default&site=puzzling&run=true) is probably running a slightly different query from the web.  At first glance I can't tell what the problem is but we're looking into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a fun one.

There was a bug in the API which was causing some search parameters to be cached from incorrect sites.  In this case, the list of top tags which are rewritten as tag search aliases.  While any site's tags could have been cached incorrectly, more often than not Stack Overflow's were, and [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) is a pretty big tag over there.

[Linux](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) is not such a large tag on Puzzling, so when aliasing kicked in the search found nothing.

This has been fixed on the backend, once everything falls out of cache (should be within 15 minutes) search for those terms should be workin again.  No app update necessary.

Comment: How come mods always get the accepts on feature-requests and mods!?